# Difference between "Merchandise" and "Goods"

Tags: meaning

In an economics and accounting context, what is the difference between *goods* and *merchandise* ?

Comment: Not all goods are merchandise. It's that simple.

Comment: Alas, far too many of what economists term goods and services are more truly regarded as evils and injuries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might help :

Goods: Object material product of economic activity used to meet any business need. Things or rights likely to produce benefits and / or grant rights of economic character are goods.

The merchandise is also a good, it’s just one that sells well.

This leads us to conclude that any property or asset that a company has earmarked for sale are called merchandise.

Reference : http://vspages.com/goods-vs-merchandise-17391/

Comment: Actually the main point for me is this (from [here](http://vspages.com/goods-vs-merchandise-17391/)): A good is any asset or object to be **used** by the company. Merchandise is any asset or object to be **sold** by the company.

Comment: "A good?" Though grammatically correct.

Answer (score 5):

There is a finely nuanced difference in the circumstances in which each is used.

*Goods* are things which some individuals and businesses both buy and sell.

*Merchandise* is something which is sold. One doesn't normally speak of the receipt of some merchandise, unless one is specifically referring to one particular supplier, as in 'We have had trouble with their merchandise before'.